# Clarification on prepareforsegue and presentModalViewController while using Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an app with a LoginViewController as the initial view.

**Note:** So in appDelegate.m, self.window.rootViewController is NOT the TabBarController.
[image]

After Auth, I present the main part of the app, which has a tabbarController (identifier:tabBar) with two tabs and one tab has a navigation controller. I am using Core Data, so I need to pass MOC.

If I use,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
[obj setSelectedIndex:0];// Which tab to show first
[self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

It works good visually. Now I need to pass the MOC. Read about PrepareToSegue method,created a segue (modal, Not shown in pic) from loginVC to my TargetViewController (TabBar>NavigationController1>View1), named the segue "LoginSegue" and used the following code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
View1 *devicelist = (View1 *)[[navController viewControllers] lastObject];
devicelist.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
}
```

The TabBar does not show. How do i set the tabbar controller in this case?

I have been trying to get a grasp on getting a reference for the Modal Tabbar, but still not clear. Can some one explain in layman terms how to handle a situation like this?

Comment: You say that you present the tab bar controller, so after that, the view on screen should be the one I think you're calling the target view controller (TabBar>NavigationController1>View1). So, if that's true, why do you then want to segue from the login controller to the one you already have on screen?

Comment: @rdelmar The initial view on screen is loginScreen. I (want to) present the tabbarController>NavigationController>View1 only after user logs in.  Thats why I tried a segue from login screen to view1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a design that doesn't use a modal transition to the tab bar controller. Modal presentations are generally supposed to be for interruptions to the normal flow of the app, not for getting your main controller on the screen. There are two alternatives, that I think are better. You can leave the login controller as the initial root view controller of the window, but then switch it out for the tab bar controller (which will be the new root view controller of the window, and the login controller will be deallocated). This usually works ok, but I think in this case where you want to pass the MOC from the app delegate (I presume) to a controller in the tab bar controller, I think a second way would be better.

The second way to do this, and the way I usually do login controllers, is to have the tab bar controller be the root view controller of the window, and then present the login controller modally from the viewDidAppear method of the initial view (which would be the one you're calling View1). If you do this presentation with animation set to NO, the login controller will be the first thing the user sees:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    static int first = 1;
    if (first) {
        LoginViewController *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
        [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = 0;
    }
}
```

The if statement is in there so the presentation doesn't happen again when you come back from the login controller (you could do something more sophisticated like having a delegate call back to View1 from the login controller indicating that the login was successful if you want, but this works).

If the login succeeds, you just dismiss the login controller, and you'll be there in your first view (if it fails, you just never dismiss it, and maybe put up a message saying the login failed).

If you go this route, then you can pass the MOC in the app delegate like this:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers][0];
View1 *devicelist = (View1 *)nav.viewControllers.lastObject;
devicelist.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see your point. I tried it out and its working. But just to know, would it be possible to tell me how to get to the tabbarcontroller>navController>View1 if the tabbar was presented modally? I feel at ease switching paths after knowing better about it. :)

Comment: Those first 3 lines in your question should show the tab bar with View1 on screen if you do that presentation from the login controller. Or, you could do it with a segue, but you would need to connect the segue from the login controller to the tab bar controller, not the navigation controller.